# JFileChooser On Java 11 , Problem Of Translation to French

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, jfilechooser, java-11

I make a migration to Java 11 and I have a problem in translation with JFileChooser panel.
I have a partial translation (In French),
Is there a Java 11 bug? do you have a solution please?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Can you update the output of `java -version` in the question? Some builds include the resources/translations for some, but not all, locales.

Comment: Hi Alan  .\bin\java.exe --version
java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: @AlanBateman by “some builds”, you mean “all builds”?

Comment: See related question: [JDK not localizing JComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61699200/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. See [the release notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#Important_Changes):

> Previous releases were translated into English, Japanese, and Simplified Chinese as well as French, German, Italian, Korean, Portuguese (Brazilian), Spanish, and Swedish. However, in JDK 11 and later, French, German, Italian, Korean, Portuguese (Brazilian), Spanish, and Swedish translations are no longer provided.

According to [JDK-8204973](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204973), the files are still in the source repository, but as far as I can see, they are included neither, in Oracle’s commercial build nor in prebuild OpenJDK bundles.

Don’t ask me, what actual problem the omission ought to solve.