# JDK not localizing JComponent

Tags: java, swing, locale

I'm using JDK 13 for a Swing application but it won't show localized buttons for `JOptionPane`:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("es-MX");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
//        JOptionPane.setDefaultLocale(locale);
//        System.out.println(JOptionPane.getDefaultLocale());
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "did it work?");
    }
}
```

When using jre 1.8 it works as expected, displaying localized titles and buttons but not when using **JDK 13.0.2**

> Java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)

`JOptionPane.getDefaultLocale()` do returns the correct locale `es_MX` is just that it fails to localize the strings.

From what I've read, I think it has to do with the `ResourceBundle`, I think JDK fails to load the bundle that corresponds to my locale.

And I don't know where to find such ResourceBundle and not really sure how to load it, maybe `ResourceBundle.getBundle("somePathOrClassInsideJDK", locale);` ?

I don't think that I need to create the `ResourceBundle` from scratch, do I?

Comment: *Unrelated:* The correct language tag is `es-MX`, not `es-mx`.

Comment: @Andreas ok, did not know that, but still, the locale gets loaded ok as `es_MX`

Comment: See related question: [JFileChooser On Java 11 , Problem Of Translation to French](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57938248/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

[JDK 11 Release Notes, Important Changes and Information](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#Important_Changes) says:

- Previous releases were translated into English, Japanese, and Simplified Chinese as well as French, German, Italian, Korean, Portuguese (Brazilian), Spanish, and Swedish. However, in JDK 11 and later, French, German, Italian, Korean, Portuguese (Brazilian), **Spanish**, and Swedish translations **are no longer provided**.

Reported as Bug [JDK-8214574](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214574) (JOptionPane confirm dialog buttons are not localized), which was Closed as Duplicate of Bug [JDK-8217485](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217485) (ModifiersExText not localized since JDK 11), which was Resolved as **Won't Fix**.

It is a result of Enhancement [JDK-8204973](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204973) (Add build support for filtering translations), which states:

> Oracle will reduce the number of languages that it maintains translations of JDK resources for. The current translations will remain in the source for now, but we need a way to filter out a set of translations at build time.
>
> Oracle will use this configuration option to filter out all but English, Japanese, Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese.